# WPF - xaml's binding not working after obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I made an application in WPF (.Net 4.7). For code protection, I am using .Net Reactor.
I am using following syntax to bind textblock to first element of list in my model.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding list[0].property1}"/>
```

This code works fine but after obfuscation, this code no longer works. I changed it to this

```
<WrapPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=list}">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding property1}"/>                                       
</WrapPanel>
```

and this bind textblock to 'property1' of list first element (what I needed). I accidentally got this solution, I don't know if it is a proper way or not. I build application without obfuscation and above also works. Questions I have regarding this are

1. Why binding is not working like usual after obfuscation?
2. Using this method, does it always bind to first element of collection? If it always bind to first element, than I will continue deployment of application without wasting more time.

Sorry for bad English!!

Comment: "*Why binding is not working like usual after obfuscation?*" -- probably because the obfuscation changed the property name, and so the binding was unable to find it. "*Using this method, does it always bind to first element of collection?*" -- that shouldn't be working at all... There's no `property1` property on `list`, presumably. It shouldn't go and start searching the elements of the list

Comment: @canton7 ! "probably because the obfuscation changed the property name, and so the binding was unable to find it."--First I also thought this but there are many properties in my model and other bindings are working perfectly fine after obfuscation. "hat shouldn't be working at all... There's no property1 property on list, presumably. It shouldn't go and start searching the elements of the list"--Using above method binding works, I can upload screenshots if u say so

Comment: Sure that `DataContext="{Binding Path=list}"` is correct, and not `DataContext="{Binding Path=list[0]}"`? The `list` object does not have a `property1`, but its first element has.

Comment: Before obfuscation my code was this `DataContext="{Binding Path=list[0]}"` but this didn't work after obfuscation, I accidentally changed it to this `DataContext="{Binding Path=list}"` and it started to work fine. It's very confusing, that's why I asked on SO

Comment: Just tried this (without any obfuscation) and surprisingly `DataContext="{Binding list}"` actually works just like `DataContext="{Binding list[0]}"`.

Comment: When binding to collections, there is always a "current item", designated by a slash in the property path. You may write your Binding like `Text="{Binding list/property1}"`

Comment: I also saw this syntax today on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?view=net-5.0). Is it confirm that 'current item' will always be first element of list?. All of my model data is loading from server, I only need first element of the list.